# Node app failing a lot with incorrect content length

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I launch my node application with npm start
It is started on port 3000 and when I am using it with browser it seem to work fine

Problem is that if I am trying to test it with ab i got extremely high number of failed requests, even with concurrency level = 1(no concurrency at all)

```
> ab -c 1 -n 50 http://127.0.0.1:3000/
...
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        35
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 35, Exceptions: 0)
```

There are no any errors in node stderr.

I realize that it may be some error in application, but asking here with hope that it might be some semi-typical nodejs issue and you can suggest me where to look.

I am using react in my application(not sure if it matters)

Comment: Are you setting `Content-Length` in your app to `string.length` instead of `Buffer.byteLength(string)`? If `string` contains multi-byte characters, the two values will not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently ab does not support situation when same url returns response of different size, assuming there is some 'length failure':

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42040